# How can I get the values of a C pointer to a Swift struct?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pointers, struct

I'm building a Swift wrapper / interface for a pre-compiled C library that is shipped with its' own header file. I have every function working except for the following. The library reads given parts of the loaded file's header. I have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    DWORD width;
    DWORD height;
    DWORD length;
    const void *data;
} T_PICTURE;
```

and a function in said library that returns a `UnsafePointer<Int8>` pointer when it is given a readable file (a part of a specific metadata, a picture to be exact).

**My question is**: how am I able to assign the data at the given memory location to a struct of that kind?

I would like to assign that space in memory to a struct of that kind, but so far I have been unable to.

*I'm positive that because I'm relatively new to programming I'm missing something crucial or at the very least I don't see something fundamental. Been looking around for days now before deciding to ask, thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you have a
`ptr: UnsafePointer<Int8>` which points to a memory location containing a `T_PICTURE` structure.

In **Swift 2** you can simply "recast" the pointer and deference it.
This would copy the data pointed-to by `ptr` to 
the `picture` variable of type `T_PICTURE`:

```
let picture = UnsafePointer<T_PICTURE>(ptr).memory
```

In **Swift 3** you'll have to "rebind" the pointer:

```
let picture = ptr.withMemoryRebound(to: T_PICTURE.self, capacity: 1) {
    $0.pointee
}
```

See [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html) for more information about the new pointer conversion
APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been here for years and just signed up to ask this as it was really a tough nut to crack. Can't believe my first question got answered so quickly and with sound success! Cheers!